# How to get horizontal scrolling percentage of an HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

How can we calculate the percentage of 'distance' covered by the scrollbar on an element between start and end?

```
<div id="container" style="overflow-x:scroll; max-width:1000px;">
  <div id="contained" style="width:3000px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('#container').scroll(function(){
    var scrollPercentage; //How to get scroll percentage?
  });
</script>
```

So, if the scrollbar is completely at the left we want to get `0`, and if it's completely at the right we want to get `100`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var scrollPercentage = 100 * this.scrollLeft / (this.scrollWidth-this.clientWidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vWDfb/3/

Or, if you really must use jQuery:

```
scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / ($('#contained').width() - $(this).width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vWDfb/5/

Answer (score 4):

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vWDfb/1/

```
$('#container').scroll(function(){
    var scrollPercentage = 100*this.scrollLeft/this.scrollWidth/(1-this.clientWidth/this.scrollWidth);
});
```

It can be useful to round that number to, for example, two decimals. Then, use

```
scrollPercentage.toFixed(2);
```

---

**Edit**: Better use

```
var scrollPercentage = 100 * this.scrollLeft / (this.scrollWidth-this.clientWidth);
```

as @Blazemonger pointed out.