# Changing CSS on percentage scrolled using query

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, scroll, percentage

I have a single page website with a fixed navigation. Each section is set to 100% of the windows height. I want to change the colour of the text in the navigation as you scroll down.

I have this code so far which is exactly what i want apart from i need the scrolling to be based on percentage not amount of pixels.

Looked everywhere for a solution, can anyone help!?

```
$(document).scroll(function(){

    var row = $('.navigation a'), scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > 70)
    {   
        row .css({"color":"#333333"});
    }
    else if (scrollTop <= 70)
    {
        row.css({"color":"#d1d0ce"});
    }
});
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222389/how-to-get-scrolling-percentage-of-an-html-element-in-javascript). This example uses horizontal scrolling, but you can adapt it for vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to calculate for yourself with `$(document).height()`? Something like

```
if ((scrollTop / $(document).height()) > 0.7) {
    row.css({"color":"#333333"});
}
```

Maybe this has to be optimized to respect the viewport height too.

```
var docHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
if ((scrollTop * 100 / docHeight) > 70) {
    row.css({"color":"#333333"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get the container height and use it to work out a percentage of the height

something like this

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var percent = 20;
    var height = $(document).height();
    var point = height / 100 * percent;

    var row = $('.navigation a'), scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > point)
    {   
        row.css({"color":"#333333"});
    }
    else if (scrollTop <= point)
    {
        row.css({"color":"#ffffff"});
    }
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/W9wqm)