# Ember.js ProgressBar based on sub-route page scroll

Tags: ember.js

I developed my own solution based on computed properties of checkbox checked. However, how one would refactor the progressBar to be a computed property of how much the page scrolled on foo1 and foo2 templates rendered on the {{outlet}} of bar? I have seen this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700020/change-progress-bar-value-based-on-scrolling), but I believe that a proper Ember.js solution to this problem may require a different approach... This is an example router:

```
this.route('bar', function() {
    this.route('foo1');
    this.route('foo2');
});
```

I created a JSFiddle with a minimal example progressBar that is divided into four sections meaning that it would require four checkboxes to fill it to 100% (which is a rather static value at the moment.)

https://jsfiddle.net/Deovandski/7sgkd1j0/

**HBS**

```
<section id="progressBarBase">
  <div {{bind-attr id="progressBarValue"}}>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</section>
<p>Checkbox 1: {{input type="checkbox" checked=checkValue_1}}{{progressBarController_1}}</p>

<p>Checkbox 2: {{input type="checkbox" checked=checkValue_2}}{{progressBarController_2}}</p>
```

**JS**

```
  // Progress Bar Value
  progressBarValue: "progress_0",
  checkValue_1: false,
  checkValue_2: false,
  // ProgressBar Controller #1
  progressBarController_1: Ember.computed('checkValue_1', function() {
    if (this.get('checkValue_1') === true) {
      if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_0") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_1');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_1") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_2');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_2") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_3');
      } else {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_4');
      }
    } else {
      if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_4") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_3');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_3") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_2');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_2") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_1');
      } else {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_0');
      }
    }
  }),
  // ProgressBar Controller #2
  progressBarController_2: Ember.computed('checkValue_2', function() {
    if (this.get('checkValue_2') === true) {
      if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_0") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_1');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_1") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_2');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_2") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_3');
      } else {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_4');
      }
    } else {
      if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_4") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_3');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_3") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_2');
      } else if (this.get('progressBarValue') === "progress_2") {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_1');
      } else {
        this.set('progressBarValue', 'progress_0');
      }
    }
  }),
```

**SCSS**

```
#progressBarBase {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  .EmberCliProgressBar {
    border: 2px solid darken($ect-header-color, 75%);
    height: 20px;
    margin: 2px auto 2px auto;
    width: 200px;
    display: flex;
    div:nth-of-type(-n+4) {
      flex-grow: 1;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  }
  #progress_0 {
    @extend .EmberCliProgressBar;
  }
  #progress_1 {
    @extend .EmberCliProgressBar;
    div:nth-of-type(-n+1) {
      background: darken($ect-header-color, 25%);
    }
  }
  #progress_2 {
    @extend .EmberCliProgressBar;
    div:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
      background: darken($ect-header-color, 25%);
    }
  }
  #progress_3 {
    @extend .EmberCliProgressBar;
    div:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
      background: darken($ect-header-color, 25%);
    }
  }
  #progress_4 {
    @extend .EmberCliProgressBar;
    div:nth-of-type(-n+4) {
      background: darken($ect-header-color, 25%);
    }
  }
}
}
```

**EDIT #1**:

I've created a [full-fledged example](http://deovandski.herokuapp.com/emberTutorial/installation) with four sub-routes and twelve steps of progression. This example also diverges from the simple one as I implemented an interface that rests between the `progress_0` string and a numeric variable in which the sub-routes interacts through increment/decrement.

The interface can be seen on my [Github](https://github.com/Deovandski/deo-embercli-website/blob/master/app/controllers/ember-tutorial/installation.js). However, I can see that this implementation is triggering "changing ProgressBarValue twice in a render" deprecation which will become an issue on Ember.js 3. Although this is a problem for its own post, I just wanted to inform you in case you wish to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ember-waypoints](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-waypoints). I started writing this out with dummy code, then just made a working version of this. See this commit on this repo: https://github.com/patrickberkeley/scroll-incrementer/commit/bebdc4796bc13b77ac4d13ab9faffa3de833eb54

Here are the important bits:

**installation/controller.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  computed,
  get,
  set
} = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  progress: 0,
  steps: 12,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    set(this, 'completedStepNames', []);
  },

  stepSize: computed('steps', function() {
    return 100 / get(this, 'steps');
  }),

  _notComplete(stepName) {
    return !get(this, 'completedStepNames').contains(stepName);
  },

  actions: {
    incrementProgress(stepName) {
      if (this._notComplete(stepName)) {
        const current = get(this, 'progress');
        const stepSize = get(this, 'stepSize');

        set(this, 'progress', current + stepSize);
        get(this, 'completedStepNames').pushObject(stepName);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**installation/template.hbs**

```
{{progress-bar
  barWidth=progress
}}

<nav>
  {{link-to 'Ubuntu' 'installation.ubuntu-virtual-box'}}
  {{link-to 'GitHub' 'installation.github'}}
</nav>

{{outlet}}
```

**installation/github/template.hbs**

```
{{#progress-section
  incrementProgress=(action 'incrementProgress' 'createAccount' target=installationController)
}}
  Create an account & install Git
{{/progress-section}}

{{#progress-section
  incrementProgress=(action 'incrementProgress' 'cloneProject' target=installationController)
}}
  Clone and setup Project
{{/progress-section}}

{{#progress-section
  incrementProgress=(action 'incrementProgress' 'versioning' target=installationController)
}}
  How to use Versioning
{{/progress-section}}
```

**components/progress-section/template.hbs**

```
{{#way-point
  on-down=(action incrementProgress)
  class='l--m-b-800'
}}
  {{yield}}
{{/way-point}}
```

**components/progress-bar/template.hbs**

```
<div class='progress-bar'>
  <div
    class='progress-bar__inner'
    style={{{concat "width: " barWidth "%;"}}}
  >
  </div>
</div>
```

**styles/app.css**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.l--m-b-800 {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}

.progress-bar {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1px;
}

.progress-bar__inner {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 10px;
}
```

**Note** you might need to adjust the actions that are triggered with waypoints on each `progress-section` by using [the offset option](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/).

Comment: Been thinking about this more and if you only ever have one progress bar on the screen at a time and you want to use it on more than the `installation` controller and its nested controllers, you could split it out into a service.