# How to link the status of an animation to the status of the scrollbar in html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So i'm building a website (html, css, js) but im not really sure how to go about achieving what I want.

Basically, i've got an animation in after effects of a pencil being sharpened for a website.  I'm trying to code the website so as the user scrolls down the page, the animation of the pencil being sharpened gets played and the pencil gets shorter.  But I want to it to work so the animation is directly linked to the scrollbar status.  So say the scroll bar is 40% down the page, I want the animation to be 40% played.  Basically I want the animation playback point to be relative to the scrollbar position.

How would I go about doing this?

Any help would be great

Comment: And you only want to use pure css for it?

Comment: Not only css, im using html javascript and css, i just dont really know where to start

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19700100/9842319. I hope it helps you.