# how to get percentage scrolled by the user?

Tags: android, scrollview

i have a scrollview with text in it and a button at the bottom. what i want to do is change the text on the button according to the percentage of scrolling done by the user. this is my code:

```
public class Verbal extends Activity implements ScrollViewListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verbal);
    ObservableScrollView scrollview = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview);
    scrollview.setScrollViewListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y,
        int oldx, int oldy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button answer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answernumber);

    int totalHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int p = (y/totalHeight)*100;

    if (p>3 && p<8)
        answer.setText("1");
    else if (p>8 && p<11)
        answer.setText("2");
    else if (p>11 && p<14)
        answer.setText("3");
    else if (p>14 && p<17)
        answer.setText("4");
    else if (p>17 && p<21) 
        answer.setText("5");
    else if (p>21 && p<25)
        answer.setText("6");
    else if (p>25 && p<29)
        answer.setText("7");
    else if (p>29 && p<31)
        answer.setText("8");
    else if (p>31 && p<35)
        answer.setText("9");
    else if (p>35 && p<39)
        answer.setText("10");
    else if (p>39 && p<45)
        answer.setText("11");
    else if (p>45 && p<50)
        answer.setText("12");
    else if (p>50 && p<56)
        answer.setText("13");
    else if (p>56 && p<62)
        answer.setText("14");
    else if (p>62 && p<67)
        answer.setText("15");
    else if (p>67 && p<72)
        answer.setText("16");
    else if (p>72 && p<78)
        answer.setText("17");
    else if (p>78 && p<83)
        answer.setText("18");
    else if (p>83 && p<86)
        answer.setText("19");
    else if (p>86)
        answer.setText("20");   




}

}
```

the problem is the text is not changing in the button because initially the value of 'y' is zero so 'p' is also zero. but as the user scrolls down value of 'y' changes and 'p' dosent change. i need to continuously change value of 'p' as 'y' changes. please help me programmatically what to do?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: i have a set of questions in the scroll view. i just want to change number text on button according to what question is the user reading.

Comment: Did you read this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614069/get-percentage-scrolled-of-an-element-with-jquery) maybe it is of some help to you

Comment: i think maybe with a do while loop i can get this working but dont know how to use it

Comment: This is how to use do while loop in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html
and this is wikipedia of do-while: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_while_loop

Comment: i dont need links. i know what is do while i am just not getting how to use in my code. it shoud be like do {..} while MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE something like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're running a integer division, and thus p is always 0.
You have to cast it to double like this:

```
 double p = ((double)y/(double)totalHeight)*100;
```

Comment: i use int coz i only want the integer part (without decimals) of the percentage. if i have 86.21 % i only want 86.

Comment: then you have use Math.round(). But with two integers you will always get 0 in this division, and for p also

Comment: yeah you are right. double is working. now i get it. thanx dude