# Get percent scrolled through an element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I can't seem to figure out how to calculate this value

While scrolling down a page, I would like to make a function that return the percertage of 'scrolled through'.

So my 0 would be when the element is on the cusp of being shown (it's at the bottom of the window, 0 pixels shown) and 100 being when the element is completely passed (the element is over the top of the window, 0 pixels shown).

I would need that to do parralax with custom animations, to make an animation that starts when the element is shown, and animates through until the element is gone.

EDIT: All Paralax plugins I see seem to force you in premade animations. I'd like to animate my own thing, so thats why I need that percent value.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614069/get-percentage-scrolled-of-an-element-with-jquery

Comment: Tried to use these functions, and it gives me the general % through of the page. Like 0 is the Top, 100% is the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used jquery. But I can help you with this function.

```
function ScrollPercent(selector) {
    var currY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var elH = document.querySelector(selector).offsetHeight;
    var elTop = document.querySelector(selector).offsetTop;
    var fullH = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    var zero = elTop - elH;
    var hundred = elTop + window.innerHeight;
    var scrollPercent = (currY - zero) / (hundred - zero);
    return scrollPercent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After asking the question, I didn't just sit on my hands and continued working on this. This seems to do what I wish to do.

```
function ScrollPercent(jQEl){
    var currY = $('html').scrollTop();
    var elH = $(jQEl).height();
    var elTop = $(jQEl).offset();
    elTop = elTop.top;
    var fullH = $('html').height();
    var zero = elTop-elH;
    var hundred = elTop+$( window ).height();
    var scrollPercent = (currY-zero)/(hundred-zero);
    return scrollPercent;
}
```