# Set percentage value to scrollLeft() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, percentage

This is a little bit confusing (and I thought that it's impossible). I found how to get the percentage of scroll amount from [Blazemonger's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222524/5376197):

```
scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / ($('#contained').width() - $(this).width());
```

Ok, this solution works great, but my **question** is how can I set the scroll amount with jQuery?

I am simultaneously scrolling two scrollable divs and I tried this:

```
$(".mycontainer").scroll(function(){    
    var scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / ($(".mycontainerContent").width() - $(this).width())
        $(".anotherContainer").scrollLeft(scrollPercentage);
});
```

But that code doesn't work.

I tried by adding the percent symbol but the result is the same - nothing happens.

```
$(".mycontainer").scroll(function(){    
    var scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / ($(".mycontainerContent").width() - $(this).width())
        $(".anotherContainer").scrollLeft(scrollPercentage.toFixed(0)+'%');
});
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT** - [jgasiorowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33122632/2821954) is kind of working:

> You need to change percentage value again to original type for scroll
>
> ```
>  var scrollValueForAnother = ($(".anotherContainer").width() -
>  $(this).width()) * (percentage / 100);
>  $(".anotherContainer").scrollLeft(scrollValueForAnother);
> ```
>
> I hope that I didn't make a mistake in calculations

but like I mentioned in the comment of his answer:

> it's kind of working, but $(".anotherContainer") reaches end before
>   $(".myContainer") reaches its end. I want to sync two scrollable areas
>   to reach their end of scroll at the same time. i hope that i could
>   explain it.

*the two scrollable areas got different widths!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change percentage value again to original type for scroll

```
var scrollValueForAnother = ($(".anotherContainer").width() - $(this).width()) * (percentage / 100);
$(".anotherContainer").scrollLeft(scrollValueForAnother);
```

I hope that I didn't make a mistake in calculations

EDIT2: I made that little fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b4d9bLnm/1/
so your code should look like that:

```
$(".mycontainer").scroll(function(){  
    var container2 = $(".anotherContainer");  
    var scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / (this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth);

    var scrollValueForAnother = (container2[0].scrollWidth -  container2[0].clientWidth) * (percentage / 100);
    $(".anotherContainer").scrollLeft(scrollValueForAnother);
});
```

Comment: it's kind of working, but $(".anotherContainer") reaches end before $(".myContainer") reaches its end. I want to sync two scrollable areas to reach their end of scroll at the same time. i hope that i could explain it.

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş I've updated my post - maybe now it will be more helpful

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm gonna approve you answer but i got one more little wish, becouse my math is so poor - could you make container 1 wider then container 2. i try to make it but failed :( actualy i need the wider container to be the lead for the little container scroll

Comment: man my situation much more complicated my slave scrollable containers content is rotated and dynamic... im lost :D no matter, you are a magician \\// TANKS

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş Updated again - now the calculations should be perfect :)

Comment: Thank you so much man, you are my savior already. Ill try it \\//