# Add CSS animation when scrolling inside div with overflow: scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to animate the `filter: blur(px);` property based on scroll amount inside a div with overflow: scroll. I've gotten the following code to give me an alter when you've scrolled to the bottom:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.modal-container').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert('end reached');
        }
    })
});
```

How can I smoothy adjust the `filter: blur(px);` amount based on scroll percentage?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222524/9496199

Comment: add some `if(scrollPercentage bla bla bla)` and change the blur then

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that like that:

```
$(function() {
  $('.modal-container').scroll(function() {

    var scrollY = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = $(this).height();
    var scrollHeight = $('#inner').height();
    var percentage = (scrollY / (scrollHeight - height)) * 100;

    $("#inner").css('filter', 'blur('+ percentage +'px)')
  })
});
```

In the variable `percentage` you can find the scroll percentage. So if you scrolled all the way through, it is 100.

After that I apply that percentage as a blur in CSS. If you don't want it to go up to `blur(100px)`, you can just multiply the percentage by something. E.g. `percentage * 0.5` makes it to go up to 50px blur, `* 0.2` up to 20px, and so on.